# Using BEM + Sass parent selectors to target child elements of modifiers without repeating class names

Tags: css, sass, bem

I'm using sass and I use the ampersand with BEM to repeat the parent selector, eg -

```
.c-block {
 background:red;
 &__element {font-size:14px;}
 &--modifier {background:blue;}
}
```

This outputs -

```
.c-block {
  background: red;
}
.c-block__element {
  font-size: 14px;
}
.c-block--modifier {
  background: blue;
}
```

Which makes future updates to the class name nice and easy - change it in one place and sorted!

Now things get more complicated with modifiers and targeting their children:

```
.c-block {
  background:red;
  &__element {font-size:14px;}
  &--modifier {background:blue;
    .c-block__element {font-size:20px;}     
  }
}
```

Note how I've had to repeat the class name '.c-block'. Is there any way to avoid this? I only want to have one class name declaration which is referenced down my styles and changed easily in one place.

Is using variables the only way to avoid class name repetition? eg -

```
.c-block {
  $class: c-block;

  background:red;
  &__element {font-size:14px;}
  &--modifier {background:blue;
    & .#{$class}__element  {font-size:20px;}
    // the above line = .c-block--modifier .c-block__element
  }
}
```

I keep thinking there must be some better sass+BEM way of doing it rather than using variables.

Comment: You can nest up to 4 levels, which is recommended. If you want to nest more than 4 levels, use variable.

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41181012/scss-bem-style-children-structure-when-parent-has-modificator

Answer (score 2):

As someone who uses BEM with SASS, your question made me curious and I found the following article (on CSS tricks) after a quick google, [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/bem-mixins/) is a link to it. Instead of using variables, we can create mixins to help achieve what you want, like so:

```
/// Block Element
/// @access public
/// @param {String} $element - Element's name
@mixin element($element) {
    &__#{$element} {
        @content;
    }
}

/// Block Modifier
/// @access public
/// @param {String} $modifier - Modifier's name
@mixin modifier($modifier) {
    &--#{$modifier} {
        @content;
    }
}
```

You can then output your SASS like so:

```
.block {
    /* CSS declarations for `.block` */

    @include element(element) {
        /* CSS declarations for `.block__element` */
    }

    @include modifier(modifier) {
        /* CSS declarations for `.block--modifier` */

        @include element(element) {
            /* CSS declarations for `.block--modifier__element` */
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps in some way!

Comment: This would work, but I would recommend using the `@at-root` rule, since this will create crazy duplication which BEM aims to resolve. Take a look at this article: http://alwaystwisted.com/articles/2014-02-27-even-easier-bem-ing-with-sass-33. Note that the `@at-root` rule is only available from versions 3.3.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Neelam! but sadly that doesn't solve the issue of referencing children of modifiers, which have their normal non-modifier name.   
In your example the child element has the parent modifier name, I want it to remain as its default element name eg - .c-block--modifier .c-block__element {/*styles*/}. I'm actually selecting a child element (adding specificity).

Sorry if i didn't explain that very well! Thanks for the mixin!