# Target sibling from modifier

Tags: html, css, sass, bem

I have a class of `.track` with a bem class of `&__waveform` inside it should return `.track__waveform`, but the parent `.track` class can have an .active on it as well, how do I target `&__waveform` inside of the `.active` modifier?

```
.track {
  &__waveform {
    display: none;
  }
  &.active {
   &__waveform {
    display: block;
   }
  }
}
```

I need it to output

```
.track.active .track__waveform {
  display:block;
}
```

I can do it just by putting the full .track__waveform class inside of the .active class, but I feel there should be a way to use a child combinator.

Comment: shouldn't the modifier be `&--active`? then you can do `&--active &__waveform` (not nested though).

Comment: @Pete yer I suppose I could do that and stick with proper bem syntax.

Comment: Not sure if that's the proper way though - I'm also learning BEM and came this came up - seems daft not to be able to nest if you have a lot of children of the active class that need changing

Comment: I guess selecting `&__transform` directly from `.track` returns `.track__transform`, but when it is nested under `.active` it will go for `.active__transform` so the answer by Paleo seems convincing.

Comment: Most people suggest the var route in one of the answers in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41181012/scss-bem-style-children-structure-when-parent-has-modificator, but perhaps the modifier should be on each child (if they need separate styles, but that may make your js a lot more convoluted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.track {
    &.active {
        .track__waveform {
            display: block;
        }
    }
}
```

that's all...

Answer (score 3):

```
.track {
    &.active &__waveform {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.active` class should be a modifier: `.track--active`

So the needed selector should be `.track--active track__waveform`.

One way to do it with sass nesting is:

```
.track {
    $block: &;

    &--active {
        #{$block}__waveform {
            display: block;
        }
    }
}
```